# How to disable specific dates in UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a **list of date** which is disable in date picker so how it's possible? have any solution for it.

Comment: you can compare to each other for change date at time.

Comment: It's possible disable before selection .like disable past date i need like this type.

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with UIDatePicker per se.

Use a UIPickerView(superclass of UIDatePicker) and customize it to leave out those dates using [UIPickerViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdatasource) and [UIPickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate).

Comment: I know this but i need in UIDate picker .

Comment: Why do you _need_ a `UIDatePicker`? You can customise a `UIPickerView` so it appears the same.

Comment: as @AshleyMills said, UIDatePicker is a special case(a subclass) of UIPickverView so there's no difference

Comment: i have list of holiday not a list of date which is show in pikcer.

Comment: so use UIPickerView

Comment: how it possible. if i have not see user holiday list

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please update your question with more information.

Comment: i have list of Date which is holiday . that's day can not select by user in UIDatepicker

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UICalendarView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicalendarview) but it's only supported in iOS 16+

if you are really want to use UIDatePicker here is a workaround first you add [addTarget(_:action:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) with a valueChanged event and you check the date each time the event fires and if the date match one of those dates you don't want the user to select, You can show error to the user or you can set a new date and that will make the UIDatePicker to skip the current date which in your case it will be the holiday date.