# How create calendar with only custom date selection allow so other date will be disable in UIDatePicker swift

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I want to allow user to select only given date from API and other date should be un-clickable or disable.

As I can check in SWIFT UIDatePicker only providing minimum date and maximum date selection but my requirement is to enable random date.

[image]

Comment: Try using UIPickerView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961436/how-to-disable-specific-dates-in-uidatepicker