# How to Disable certain dates in Date Picker in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I want to disable certain dates in the date picker, for example, I want to disable holidays and weekend dates in a date picker so the user can't select those dates. Is there any way to disable specific dates?

Comment: You will find a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961436/how-to-disable-specific-dates-in-uidatepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UICalendarView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicalendarview) but it's only supported in iOS 16+ and it only works with dates not dates and time.

if you are really want to use UIDatePicker here is a workaround first you add [addTarget(_:action:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) with a valueChanged event and you check the date each time the event fires and if the date match one of those dates you don't want the user to select, You can show error to the user or you can set a new date and that will make the UIDatePicker to skip the current date which in your case it will be the holiday date.